# Approximation of $e$ by a rational number

Tags: calculus

I am having a problem with the final question of this exercise.

Show that $e$ is irrational (I did that). Then find the first $5$ digits in a decimal expansion of $e$ ($2.71828$).

Can you approximate $e$ by a rational number with error $< 10^{-1000}$ ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, you can. Do you need to give such a number? Do you know about continued fractions?

Comment: I don't think I need to find the actual number. But I think I have to just prove its existence. 
I never actually manipulated with continued fractions

Comment: This question is very unclear. It could mean one of three things: 1: Can e be approximated by such a rational? Answer: Yes, obviously -- every real number can. 2: Do you know how to approximate it? Answer: Yes, in principle. 3: Find such a rational. Answer: Give me a few moments...

Comment: I think that a more interesting question is whether there is a good short rational approximation to e, analogous to 355/113 for $\pi$. Approximating e to absurd accuracy is just donkeywork for a computer. What puzzles me here is: if you are a good enough mathematician to prove that e is irrational, why would you ask such a naive question?

Answer (score 4):

In the standard proof that $e$ is irrational, one first proves that
$$
0 < e -s_n < \frac1{n!n}
\qquad\mbox{where}\qquad
s_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{k!}
$$
So you only need to find $n$ such that $\frac1{n!n}< 10^{-1000}$ or $n!>10^{1000}$. You can use Stirling's approximation for that I guess. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+n%21%3E+10%5E1000) says $n=450$ suffices.

Comment: I would think that stating that such an n exists would probably suffice for this question. One could show the Taylor expansion for e has an Nth term such that all n > N terms will be smaller than 10^{-1000}.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think we have to really know anything about $e$ to say that
we can approximate it with a rational number with an error less then
$10^{-1000}$.

Say $e=a_0.a_1 a_2 \ldots$

There is clearly a rational number $q=a_0.a_1 \ldots a_{1001}$ and
$|q-e|\leq10^{-1000}$ (note that the difference is bounded by a geometric
sum)

Comment: Note that the question asks for an error less than $10^{-1000}$.

Comment: @robjohn - thanks for pointing that out, I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If `2.71828` are the first few digits of $e$ the we have $$2.71828 < e < 2.71829$$ Put $q = 271828/100000$ we deduce $$0 < e-q < 0.00001 = 10^{-5}.$$

Comment: What does this answer ?

Comment: @Belgi, think a bit. it shows how to solve the question asked

Comment: @spernerslemma: does it give any more of a hint than do either of the previous answers?

Comment: The question did not ask for a rational approximation with error less then $10^{-5}$.

Comment: @Belgi: extrapolate by changing 5 to 1000, but don't write $e$ to 1000 places :-)

Comment: @robjohn - it seems that the answer uses the fact that the OP calculated the first five digits of $e$. However, the OP did not calculate $1000$ digits of $e$

Comment: @Belgi: the question is "Can you approximate $e$..." not "Approximate $e$..." No answer actually computes a rational approximation of $e$ to an error of less than $10^{-1000}$.